# Видеоплеер для WinForms

Tags: c#, winforms

В WinForm приложение нужно **встроить** видео плеер.
Необходимы в основном только базовые команды - воспроизведение, пауза, стоп, перемотка (переместиться в заданное время) и управление громкостью.
Мне известны - windows media player, vlc plugin.
Подскажите известные **альтернативы**.

Comment: Вас интересует другие плеера для WinForms, кроме как media player, vlc или различные способы внедрения этих плееров в WinForms?

Comment: Интересуют другие плееры.

Comment: У GOM Player'а тоже есть com-объект. А что именно надо сделать? Т. е. из-за чего перечисленные не подошли?

Comment: WMP не умеет воспроизводить некоторые файлы(контейнеры кодеки, я в этом не силен). VLC плагин (com) попросту не работает. К последнему вроде как есть несколько open source проектов для внедрения, и все давно заброшены/не обновлялись.

Answer (score 1):

Есть [Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/playing-avi-files-using-directx-9-with-C-Sharp-and-net/)

Есть [Shockwave flash object](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=714w3HQDTcA) он же YouTube Player (COM компонент)

Можете использовать MediaElement (через [ElementHost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.integration.elementhost.aspx)) из WPF, это обертка над Windows Media Player

Answer (score 0):

не надо никаких плееров
mciSendString умеет все

Comment: Сделать бочку может? Я тут ищу способы воспросизведения и управления этим процессом с максимальной всеядностью в рамках WinForms.

Comment: Пожалуйста, обоснуйте свой ответ, чтобы он был более информативным и полезным.

Comment: mciSendString умеет проигрывать любые медиафайлы, а так же управлять громкостью, балансом, остановкой, продолжением и т.д. и т.п.

Comment: А можно увидеть пример?

Comment: В Инете их море.  Только, чтобы дать понятие, приведу:

Comment: [DllImport("winmm.dll")]
        private static extern long mciSendString(string command, StringBuilder returned, int len, IntPtr callback);     
        private void PlayFile(string fileName)
        {
            string command = "close MediaFile";
            mciSendString(command, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            command = "open \"" + fileName + "\" type mpegvideo alias MediaFile";
            mciSendString(command, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);
            command = "play MediaFile";                mciSendString(command, null, 0, IntPtr.Zero);

        }